# Rewriting back to a file after splitting all whitespace?

Tags: python, file, list, file-io

I have an interesting question. I split up the white space in a file using the following:

```
words = []
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
  words = f.read().split()
```

After that, I replaced some strings in the file with other words, and stored everything into the `words` list. However, now that I have everything into a list, I want to write the contents back into the same file with all the white space still there. I also want all the words I replaced to be in the places where their original words were. Would this be possible to do, if at all? If so, could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want `re.split`, and create a group to preserve whitespace:

```
In [3]: re.split("(\s+)", "this is a test! Hello world.")
Out[3]: ['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'test!', ' ', 'Hello', ' ', 'world.']
```

Note this will preserve newlines, if your document contains them.

Comment: Would it be possible to use re.split with a list? It's because my file contents are first read and placed into a giant list.

Comment: I think what you want to do is: `words = re.split("(\s+)", f.read())`.

Comment: Ah okay thanks guys! Now I am trying to write back to the file after I replaced the words but my format is coming out weird...this is how I wrote back out to the file after I used `re.split` to preserve the whitespace: `with open(fname, 'w') as f: for item in words: f.write("%s" %item)`

But my formatting is off. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's just that when I rewrite to the file, the file structure does not seem to be preserved... plus I don't end up replacing all the words I want. I think it has to do with how I am writing to the file.

Comment: This sounds like a different issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(fname, 'w'+) as fh: 
    fh.write(' '.join(words))
```

The order should be preserved, since the `words` list maintain them in the same order.

---

**Edit:** The following creates a nested list of the form `list[0] = ['Hello', 'there!']`, which implies that you'll have to update the code that changes the strings you mentioned in your question.

```
with open(infile, 'r') as fh:
    input = fh.read().split('\n')

lines = []
for line in input:
    lines.append(line.split(' '))
```

To write it back to the file, something like the following should suffice:

```
with open(outfile, 'w+') as fh:
    for line in lines:
        fh.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
```

Comment: I need it to preserve newlines also, would that be possible?

Comment: With your original snippet for reading the input file, no, since it discards that information; if you'd instead first read the input line by line (i.e. splitting on '\n'), then splitting each line's content, you'll acheive the result you want. I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: Hm, thanks for this! This works well. I'm now just having trouble   finding if a string is in the list of the list of strings :P.

Comment: A for-loop and list.index() should solve that for you.

It just struck me, though, that if you're doing all of this only to replace some words, there's a much simpler way to do it -- string.replace(). You could simply read your entire file (or process line by line if it's very large), and apply current_line = current_line.replace(old, new) (iterating over a list if you've got multiple words to replace).

Comment: Hm, interesting...It's just that my string.replace was getting kind of messed up with the newlines and the white spaces and I want the formatting to be the same as I had previously. Plus, when I read from a file, I wanted to replace the lines, but there is no way to do so without creating another file...that's why I wanted to use a list. I'll try it out your suggestion and see what I can do but I may ask for more help! Thanks!